# Repeated two way anova in R

Tags: r, anova

I would like to do a two way repeated anova in R. My data includes three species (A, B, C) subjected to three treatments (1,2,3) - there were 3 replicates of each treatment. Class data (1-5) on each species in each treatment was collected before treatment, 1 year after treatment, 3 years after treatment and 5 years after treatment. I don't know how to go about starting the analysis in R, any help please with similar examples??

Comment: When you say 'class data', do you mean that your response variable was measured on an ordinal scale from 1 to 5?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to use the "anova" function from the "car" package. R Bloggers has [a great tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-tutorial-series-two-way-repeated-measures-anova/) on doing a two-way repeated measures ANOVA with that method, including guidance on how to reshape your data appropriately.

Comment: That function in `car` is named `Anova()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use package nlme in R for repeated measures ANOVA/REML, with good flexibility for specifying your random effects. Some more information here:
http://rcompanion.org/handbook/I_09.html

However, as your response variable is ordinal rather than continuous, so violating one of the assumptions of ANOVA, I do not think you should be using ANOVA at all.

An alternative is a cumulative link model, which you can fit using package 'ordinal' in R, and the function 'clm' or 'clmm2', for example.

Individual would certainly be a random effect, which I think you can specify as 'random=individual' for 'clm'. As you don't expect a treatment effect before the treatment was applied, I think you need to be careful how you include time point in the model, but possibly you could use nesting or treat time as a random effect - I'm not quite sure how best to approach that (any suggestions?).